# Jmeter is exiting without executing all threads

Tags: jmeter

I am using a high performance cloud machine with 16GB RAM. I need to run execute 25 APIs for 66720 thread in 60 minutes with 10 minute session time for each user. I am running following configuration:

```
Threads: 66720
Ramp Up: 3600
Loop: 1
```

Transaction controller with 25 API's with constant timer: 24 sec.
As per hour calculation test should finish within 2 Hours. I am running test in non-gui mode but it runs just for approximately 32328 users and exits the test smoothly without any error within an hour. Can anyone help me to know why all threads are not running?

Comment: are you trying to run 66720 threads one one machine or is it a distributed test?